# Pandas Plot: How to change xlim in datatime format?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The range of date is from 2020-01-30 to 2020-03-31. The format of Date is datetime64[ns]. 
I want to change the xlim range to (2020-01-30, 2020-03-31), but not working.

My code is as follows:

```
#Plot left Y
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig.autofmt_xdate()

x_lim = (datetime.date(2020, 1, 30), datetime.date(2020, 3, 31))

df.plot(x = 'Date', y = ["TotalCount", "CumVirusCount"], ax = ax1, xlim = x_lim)


Plot right (Y)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df.plot(x = 'Date', y = ["Percent"], ax = ax2, xlim = x_lim, ylim=(0,70), color = 'tab:green')

#Decorations
#ax1:
ax1.set_xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
ax2.set_ylabel("Percentage")

plt.show()
```

The plot is as follows:

[image: Plot]

I expect the first date to be 2020-01-30 and the last date to be 2020-03-31 on the x-axis.

How to make that happen? Why my approach doesn't work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do set the x-range in your code with `xlim=...`, and it works fine. But the ticks that matplotlib places on the x-axis by default do not necessarily include the min and max values. To change that, you have to change the ticks, not the range. Pandas' `df.plot()` wrapper takes an `xticks` keyword argument for this, e.g. pass this in the plot function call:

```
xticks=[x_lim[0], <some in-between dates to label>, x_lim[1]]
```

Comment: I  changed the xticks. I believe it worked, only that the xticks now show the year only, not the month and day. Do you know why?

Comment: I think this is another issue. I will open another question.

Comment: Using ax1.set_xticks(x_ticks) and ax2.set_xticks(x_ticks) shows the date properly. Directly passing in shows only the year.

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of that behavior.

Comment: This is probably because the format of my Date is datetime64[ns]. There is a mismatch with my ticks, which are in date only.